Majorization theory on $\sigma$-finite measure spaces
I want to learn about majorization and submajorization theory on $\sigma$-finite measure spaces. I know things get a bit more complicated compared with the case of a finite measure spaces but I'm mostly interested in the case of nonnegative functions where most of these difficulties disappear. What are good references?
In particular, I'm looking for a proof of the following result:
Let $(X,\mu)$, $(Y,\nu)$ be $\sigma$-finite measure spaces and let $f\in L^1(X,\mu)^+$ and $g\in L^1(Y,\nu)^+$ be nonnegative functions with right-continuous decreasing rearrangements $f^*, g^* \in L^1(\mathbb R^+)$.
Then the following are (supposedly) equivalent:

$f\succeq g$, defined as $\int_0^t f^*(s)ds \le \int_0^t g^*(s)ds$ for all $t>0$.
There exists a doubly substochastic operator $\varphi:L^1(X,\mu)\to L^1(Y,\nu)$ with $\varphi(f)=g$.
There exists a doubly substochastic integral kernel $P(t,s)$ such that $f^*(t)=\int_0^\infty P(t,s)g^*(s)ds$.
For all all convex functions $\phi:\mathbb R^+\to \mathbb R^+$ with $\phi(0)=0$, $\int \phi\circ f \,d\mu \le \int \phi\circ g \, d\nu$

I'm also interested in whether there is a canonical choice of integral kernel $P(t,s)$?

Edit: The equivalence of items 1 and 4 is proved in [1, Theorem 2.1] but I'm still interested in the existence of the doubly substochastic map.
Item 2 follows from 3 since a nonnegative $L^1$ function and its decreasing rearrangement can be interconverted via doubly substochastic maps.

[1] Joe, Harry, Majorization, randomness and dependence for multivariate distributions, Ann. Probab. 15, 1217-1225 (1987). ZBL0657.60022.
